# convertir una funcion a ES6

Tags: javascript

mi funcion es:

```
function filter_list(arrays) {
 return  arrays.filter(function(current){
  if(typeof current==="number"){
    return current;
  }
 });
}

console.log(filter_list([1,2,'a','b']));
```

queria convertirlo asi

```js
function filter_list(arrays) {
  return arrays.filter(arrays.filter(current => typeof current === "number");
  }

  console.log(filter_list([1, 2, 'a', 'b']));
```

pero sale error!!!

Comment: Son errores tipográficos, voto para cerrar por este motivo. El return debería ser: `return arrays.filter(current => typeof current === "number"); `

Answer (score 1):

Estas llamando `arrays.filter` 2 veces!
La primera declaración de `arrays.filter(` sobra.

```js
function filter_list(arrays) {
  return arrays.filter(current => typeof current === 'number');
}

console.log(filter_list([1, 2, 'a', 'b']));
```

Answer (score 1):

Sintacticamente te falta un parentesis y funcionalmente no es necesario usar el método filter 2 veces.

Te dejo como seria en ES6:

```js
var filterList = arr => arr.filter(cur => typeof cur === 'number');

console.log(filterList([1,2,'a','b']));
```